# How to let the user bind a click handler function to a button?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I am currently building my own GUI using the SDL2 library for a program i wrote in C (**c89**).

## Problem

I want to let the user of my code pass its own click handler function, which would be called every time a click event is fired on the surface of the corresponding button.

## What I tried

I thought i could use *function pointers* like this :

```c
bind_ClickHandler(void (*function)(void)) {/* bind it to a button */}
```

but, obviously, it is too limiting for the user.

So i tried to use *stdarg.h* :

```c
/* ... : arguments to pass to the click handler */
bind_ClickHandler(void (*function)(), int nb_args, ...) 
{ 
     void *arg_pt;
     va_list args;
     va_start(args, nb_args);
     /* I don't know what to do so i cast it as a garbage pointer */
     arg_pt = va_arg(args, void *);
     
     /* repeat this in a loop to save the args and bind the click handler to a button */ 
}
```

With this code i can pass arguments to the click handler, but only if i know their **types**.

## What I want

I want to use something like the second piece of code i showed you to save the args to pass to the click handler, but it doesn't work because i need to know the types of the args to use *va_arg()*.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass a single `void*` pointer. Like [`qsort_r`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort_r.3.html) or [`pthread_create`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html)[*]. The user only needs one pointer - and that pointer will point anywhere the user wants to.

```
void (*clickhandler_user_function)(void *) = NULL;
void *clickhandler_user_function_arg = NULL;
void bind_ClickHandler(void (*function)(void*arg), void *function_arg) {
    // store function and fucntion_arg somewhere
    clickhandler_user_function = function;
    clickhandler_user_function_arg = function_arg;
}
```

A single pointer is just enough:

```
struct user_context_s {
    int some_number;
    const char *some string;
    // etc.
};
void user_function_that_operates_on_user_context(void *p) {
   struct user_context_s *ctx = p;
   printf("My number is: %d\n", ctx->some_number);
}
int main() {
    // user can use malloc() and manage the lifetime of it's context
    struct user_context_s ctx = {1, "blabla"};
    bind_ClickHandler(user_function_that_operates_on_user_context, &user_context);
}
```

[*] -  or [`thrd_create`](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.26.5.1) or [`fopencookie`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Streams-and-Cookies.html) uses `void *cookie` or the standard [`sigevent`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sigevent.7.html) uses `void *sival_ptr;` in `sigval` to pass context when `sigev_notify == SIGEV_THREAD`.

Comment: So i have just to let the user pass a pointer to the args and i call the click handler with this pointer ? That's great but it requires the user to design its function to use this pointer if he wants to use the GUI.

Comment: `i have just to let the user pass a pointer to the args and i call the click handler with this pointer ?` Yes. `but it requires the user to design its function to use this pointer if he wants to use the GUI` Yes. C does not have [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function).

Comment: I like your solution because it keeps complexity very low on my side but i'd like to know if there's a way to allow the user to pass the arguments to my _bind function_ as if he was calling the click handler.

Comment: No. C does not have closures. This is what in C++ `std::bind` and `std::function` and lambdas are for. You could implement it by knowing beforehand the type and count of arguments passed to the function and allocating memory to store the values of the arguments. And this is what in C++ `template` is for and what `std::bind` actually does. This is C. C does not have templates. C does not have closures.